# PHP loop depending on number of folders

Tags: php, loops, templates, include

I am working on a project which is a sort of FAQ made in HTML and PHP (based on Bootstrap).

Some people with limited knowledge in HTML/PHP will need to update it regularly so I decided to use the "include" feature in PHP to call some .txt files. Then, the people who will update it will just have to modify the simple .txt files, which doesn't require any coding knowledge.

The text files are stored in faq/main-category/sub-category/1/question.txt and the same with "answer.php" (both in the same folder).

The FAQ items are identified with numbers (which you can see on the screenshot below). These numbers refer to the directory ("1" in the .txt file path above) where the files are.

[Screenshot of list of FAQ items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMLB8.png)

Now, here's the thing: I want to allow people who will modify it to add some new FAQ items easily. The idea is for them to only have to create a new folder (let's say "4") in the FTP server, and it would be automatically listed on the FAQ.

For this, I need that the plugin detects all items in the FTP server and list them all. I believe that is possible with a loop, however, I have no idea how...

Can anyone help with that? Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Here is the current code for the first FAQ item of the screenshot:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <?php include('../faqs/professionals/eligibility-conditions/1/question.txt'); ?>
        </a>
      </h5>
      <small>1</small>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div><p><?php include('../faqs/professionals/eligibility-conditions/1/answer.txt'); ?></p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

You will see both "include" codes that call the .txt files for the question and for the answer.

[Here is a screenshot of the file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCqlQ.png)

Comment: Personally If I was to make a CMS however small, like in your case, then I would use a database (e.g. MySQL). Then you could set up a couple of 'admin' pages where non technical members could reply etc. This would also help if you wanted to add extra functionality for example being able to flag questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("../faqs/professionals/eligibility-conditions/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $foldername) {
?>
  <div id="accordion" role="tablist">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <?php include($foldername.'/question.txt'); ?>
        </a>
      </h5>
      <small>1</small>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div><p><?php include($foldername.'/answer.txt'); ?></p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly! I just added a small piece of code inside the <small></small> so it would show the right number (based on the name of the folder where the question and answer are stored).

Here is the code I added: <?php echo basename($foldername) ?>

Comment: yeah, it seems I missed that one. Glad it worked right for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your application structure, maybe you are using MVC architecture but you can do it like below.

Create a PHP function which will return an array with questions and answers

```
<?php
function get_faqs(){
    $folderpath = 'faqs/shared/'; //change as per your desired path
    if(scandir($folderpath)){
        $file_arr = scandir($folderpath);
        foreach ($file_arr as $val){
            if($val == '.' || $val == '..'){ 
                continue; 
            } else if(scandir($folderpath.$val)){           
                $faq_arr = scandir($folderpath.$val);
                foreach ($faq_arr as $file){
                    if($file == '.' || $file == '..'){ 
                        continue; 
                    } else if($file == 'question.txt'){
                        $faq_final[$val]['question'] = file_get_contents($folderpath.$val.'/'.$file);
                    } else if($file == 'answer.txt'){
                        $faq_final[$val]['answer'] = file_get_contents($folderpath.$val.'/'.$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $faq_final;
}
?>
```

Then iterate that array in your HTML as below

```
<?php
$faqs = get_faqs(); // you need to call this in controller if you have MVC application
?>
<div id="accordion" role="tablist">
<?php foreach ($faqs as $num => $data) { ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex w-100 justify-content-between" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <?php echo $data['question']; ?>
                </a>
            </h5>
            <small><?php echo $num; ?></small>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div><p><?php echo $data['answer']; ?></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I got some errors when I tried to use this code... Thank you anyway! :)